# \r\n in API results - How to get rid of that

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

You can see an example by visiting this link http://www.recipepuppy.com/api/?i=butter

The relevant part of the JSON is:

```
{  
  ...
  "results":[
    ...
    {  
    "title":"Fudge Fondue \r\n\t\t\r\n\t\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\r\n\t\r\n\r\n",
    "href":"http:\/\/www.kraftfoods.com\/kf\/recipes\/fudge-fondue-51563.aspx",
    "ingredients":"hot fudge, butter",
    "thumbnail":"http:\/\/img.recipepuppy.com\/611087.jpg"
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

I'm building this app with react native but I guess it doesn't matter the language used, it will always add these annoying lines.

Are there any solutions for this?

I know I can use something like this `.replace(/[\r\n]/g, "");` but I don't know exactly how I should handle it,the api returns a single array that I store in `data=responseJson.results` then inside the view I am rendering the titles causing the issue with FlatList like so

```
<FlatList
data={this.state.data}
keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.href}
ListEmptyComponent={this.noItemDisplay}
renderItem={({ item, index }) => (

            <Body>
              <Text>{item.title}</Text>
            </Body>
)}/>
```

Comment: you can trim the excess \r\n\t in data or renderItem props by using the replace function as you already know. In case you didn't know, you can pass a function to data props just like renderItem.

Comment: what's your `expected result`?

Comment: @flix plain text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JavaScript trim() method removes white space from both ends of a string, but not anywhere in between. Whitespace can be tabs or spaces

```js
title= "Fudge Fondue \r\n\t\t\r\n\t\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\r\n\t\r\n\r\n";

tileAfterRemovingSpaces = title.trim();

console.log("tileAfterRemovingSpaces", tileAfterRemovingSpaces)
```

[Source](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-index-split-and-manipulate-strings-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for my naive answer that was a mistake on my part.

Here is a more in depth summary albeit rather theoretical.

According to the article  [Article on the nl2br line-break](https://medium.com/@kevinsimper/react-newline-to-break-nl2br-a1c240ba746) you cannot use the following since this would return a string with DOM nodes inside(it has to be a string only) :

```
this.state.text.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />')
```

Furthermore, something such as this:

```
{this.props.text.split(“\n”).map(function(item) {
  return (
    {item}
    <br/>
  )
})}
```

Would not work either because React including React Native is pure functions and ***two functions can be next to each other***.

So a solution would be to wrap each line break in a span because of span's inline display, let's take a look in the following code:

```
{this.props.section.text.split(“\n”).map(function(item, i) {
  return (
    <span key={i}>
      {item}
      <br/>
    </span>
  )
})}
```

I hope this answer provides some insight to your particular case!
Feel free to leave comments. And thanks to Jon @Jon P for pointing out my erroneous ways.

Comment: I've summarized the article into a more compact and comprehensible version instead of a link and brief caption.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time